# Kali - обрыв интернета

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, network-manager

Есть ноут со свежей установленной Debian- based Kali 2020.2. Устанавливал с dvd образа. WiFi раздаю с точки на телефоне ( андроид). Kali с удовольствием коннектиться через Network Manager. Ping - вечен и прекрасен.

Проблема: при попытке запустить браузер или apt update - ping навечно обрывается. При этом коннект к WiFi не обрывается  - тупо пропадает интернет до рестарта манагера. Дальше всё повторяется. Пробовал отрубить Network Manager и настроить через wpa_supplicant - тоже самое. Карта на борту BCM4313 802.11bgn.

Comment: Открывайте логи, наверняка там есть какая-либо информация.

Comment: Ещё вариант: а оператор позволяет раздавать интернет? Возможно причина в блокировке соединения при первом обращении к какому-либо сайту.

Comment: Трассировка маршрута после пропадания соединения - где?

Answer (score 0):

Класически в качестве **init** системы долгое время использовались **Sys-v** или **Open RC**. Но последнее время всё чаще в уже "*собранных*" или "*производных*" дистрибутивах по умолчанию используется **Systemd**, которая берет на себя ответственность за контроль практически "всего" ( чем и вызывает массу критики консервативного линукс сообществе в свой адрес ).

Для корректной работы c **AP** в режиме **Ad-Hoc** и получения динамического **IPv4** в конфигурации **Systemd** должны быть соответственные инструкции

```
#/etc/systemd/network/25-wireless.network

[Match]
Name=wlp2s0b1 # именование беспроводного интерфейса

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

Детальнее [здесь](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9))